# failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker-compose, nextcloud, letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion

I am Implementing a containerized nextcloud application with a self signed cert using the example docker compose file provided here: https://github.com/nextcloud/docker/blob/master/.examples/docker-compose/with-nginx-proxy/mariadb/apache/docker-compose.yml (also using the provided .env, .conf and Dockerfile provided)

my file structure

```
docker-compose.yml
db.env
proxy/uploadsize.conf
proxy/Dockerfile
```

my docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: mariadb:10.5
    command: --transaction-isolation=READ-COMMITTED --binlog-format=ROW
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=<password>
      - MARIADB_AUTO_UPGRADE=1
      - MARIADB_DISABLE_UPGRADE_BACKUP=1
    env_file:
      - db.env

  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    restart: always

  app:
    image: nextcloud:apache
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - nextcloud:/var/www/html
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=servhostname.local
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=servhostname.local
      - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=my@example.com
      - MYSQL_HOST=db
      - REDIS_HOST=redis
    env_file:
      - db.env
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
    networks:
      - proxy-tier
      - default

  cron:
    image: nextcloud:apache
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - nextcloud:/var/www/html
    entrypoint: /cron.sh
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis

  proxy:
    build: ./proxy
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    labels:
      com.github.jrcs.letsencrypt_nginx_proxy_companion.nginx_proxy: "true"
    volumes:
      - certs:/etc/nginx/certs:ro
      - vhost.d:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
    networks:
      - proxy-tier

  letsencrypt-companion:
    image: nginxproxy/acme-companion
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - certs:/etc/nginx/certs
      - acme:/etc/acme.sh
      - vhost.d:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
    networks:
      - proxy-tier
    depends_on:
      - proxy

# self signed
  omgwtfssl:
    image: paulczar/omgwtfssl
    restart: "no"
    volumes:
      - certs:/certs
    environment:
      - SSL_SUBJECT=servhostname.local
      - CA_SUBJECT=my@example.com
      - SSL_KEY=/certs/servhostname.local.key
      - SSL_CSR=/certs/servhostname.local.csr
      - SSL_CERT=/certs/servhostname.local.crt
    networks:
      - proxy-tier

volumes:
  db:
  nextcloud:
  certs:
  acme:
  vhost.d:
  html:

networks:
  proxy-tier:
```

This works on my Windows Machine, However I want to have this running on a linux Machine. When i run the same docker-compose.yml file in linux (raspbian pi 1GB RAM && ubuntu laptop 6GB RAM) I get the error

> failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount218034811/Dockerfile: no such file or directory

before install I did run apt-get update && upgrade

I tried to build the Docker file in the proxy folder

- on Windows we get a successful build
- on linux we get the following output

> $ docker build . [+] Building 0.5s (2/2) FINISHED  => [internal] load
> build definition from Dockerfile
> 0.3s  => => transferring dockerfile: 2B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s  => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        0.4s  => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          0.0s failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: open
> /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount789252587/Dockerfile: no such file
> or directory

---

### Update

I am able to get the docker-compose file to work by getting rid of the docker file in the proxy folder and doing a bind on the proxy folder with the /etc/nginx/conf.d folder. however if anyone knows why the configuration would not work as it please let me know.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Do you also have the `poxy` folder and its content (the `Dockerfile`) not that PI?

Comment: yes I have the proxy folder with both files in the same folder as the docker-compose.yml file